# Prove the theorem about cardinality of subgroup

Tags: group-theory

$G$ is a group.

> If $H, K \le G, |H|, |K| < \infty$, then $$|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}$$

How to prove it?

**UPD:**

I tried to prove that this function is bijective:

[image]

So if i prove it, I can do next thing:

[image]

But how to prove it?

Comment: How did you try to prove it?

Comment: Have you studied quotient groups? Do cosets ring a bell? Group theory is an extensive subject. What is the context? What do you know? Depending on the approach of the instructor, there might be an 'obvious' method.

Comment: Look Herstien's Algebra book. I detailed easy proof is given.

Comment: @BorisNovikov I added my thoughts about how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint (1): define a map $\phi: H \times K \rightarrow HK$, by $\phi((h,k))=hk$. Try to show that an element $g \in HK$ has exactly $|H \cap K|$ preimages. (No need to introduce cosets here!)

Hint (2): if $x \in H \cap K$, then $\phi((hx,x^{-1}k))=\phi((h,k))$.